# Why doesn't $x^4 = -16$ have a solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The bottom of the page: [Solution to a problem.](http://www.slader.com/textbook/9780840068132-algebra-and-trigonometry-3rd-edition/102/exercises/44/)

Shouldn't the answer be $x=-2$?

Comment: $(-2)^4 = (-2)(-2)(-2)(-2) = (4)(4) = 16$

Comment: However, $(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2}i)^4 = (4i)^2 = -16$

Comment: Why should $x=-2$ hold ?

Comment: I know, I didn't bother to double check, sorry.

Comment: For completeness, if you allow complex numbers there are four roots, $(\pm \sqrt(2) \pm i\sqrt(2))$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because $(-2)^4 = 16$ and not $-16$.

Even powers of real numbers are never negative.

If you allow complex numbers, the situation changes, but $-2$ still wouldn't be a solution.

Comment: Ah yes, damn! I didn't even bother to double check.

Comment: Right below the equation (on the page you linked to), there was already the remark "$x^4 \ge 0$" ;-).

Answer (score 4):

$x^4=-16$; $y=x^4$ and $y=-16$ graphics are disjoint

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, $x^4 = -16$ does actually have a solution, but they are in $\mathbb{C}$. As Tom Collinge already said in the comments, the solutions are $\pm \sqrt{2}, \pm i\sqrt{2}$.